# First image not showing image to video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am very new to ffmpeg and trying to convert a series of images to a video.

The command I am using (copied/modified from a tutorial)

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -start_number 1 -i dog%01d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt rgb24 dog.mp4
```

Basically, I have 4 images labelled dog1.jpg, dog2.jpg, dog3.jpg and dog4.jpg.

The problem is the output video I get has image starting at "dog2.jpg" and ending at "dog4.jpg" meaning that it is missing the first image in the sequence (i.e dog1.jpg).

I tried with different image combinations and the same behavior happened, the resulting video never had the first image in the sequence.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated, but why `-pix_fmt rgb24`? I expected to see `-pix_fmt yuv420p` instead so most non-FFmpeg based players can decode it too. Trying to force rgb24 will likely result in an output using yuv444p. If you really want RGB output you can use the `libx264rgb` encoder instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change **dog%01d.jpg** to **dog%d.jpg**.

**%01d** means sequential numbers with one leading zero

```
For example the pattern "img-%03d.bmp" will match a sequence of filenames
of the form img-001.bmp,    img-002.bmp, ..., img-010.bmp, etc.
```

I think this might also be helpful.

```
start_number
Set the index of the file matched by the image file pattern to start to read from. 
Default value is 0.

start_number_range
Set the index interval range to check when looking for the first image file in the sequence, 
starting from start_number. Default value is 5.
```

You can find more info at [FFmpeg image file demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).